# Printing Column Headers from Listview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

How do I include the column items of the `Listview` to be printed? All it prints are the items, so what should I do with this?

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form9

  Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim prn As New Printing.PrintDocument
    prn.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString()
    AddHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
    prn.Print()
    RemoveHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
  End Sub

  Private Sub PrintPageHandler(sender As Object, args As PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim lvwItem As ListViewItem
    Dim lvwSubItem As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
    Dim xPos As Integer = 0
    Dim yPos As Integer = 0
    Dim listviewcount As Integer = 1

    For Each lvwItem In lvPeople.Items
      xPos = 0
      For Each lvwSubItem In lvwItem.SubItems
        xPos += 100
        yPos = 100 + (listviewcount * 15)
        args.Graphics.DrawString(lvwSubItem.Text(), _
                New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), _
                Brushes.Black, xPos, yPos)
      Next
      listviewcount += 1
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `lvPeople.Columns(n).Text)`

Comment: uhm where should i put this again? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go through the Columns collection before you loop through your items:

```
yPos = 100
Using headerFont As New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
  For Each ch As ColumnHeader In lvPeople.Columns
    xPos += 100
    args.Graphics.DrawString(ch.Text, headerFont, Brushes.Black, xPos, yPos)
  Next
End Using
```